# What does this mean in javascript?? var leave =<%=seconds %>;

Tags: javascript

I got this code from net but i'm not able to interpret its meaning..

```
var leave =<%=seconds %>;
```

Kindly help me...

Answer (score 5):

That's not JavaScript. That's Java script generated by a server side template/scripting language such as JSP or ASP.NET.

So, when your server process the output that will be send to the browser your JavaScript will actually look like:

```
var leave = 40;
```

Where `40` is the value of `seconds` variable in the server side scripting language you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a mixture of JS and (e.g) ASP:

- `var leave` create a new variable called leave
- `<%=...%>` is the shorthand for outputting a value in ASP
- `seconds` is an ASP variable

Answer (score 0):

It is to refer or access serverside control on client side.

```
<asp:Textbox id="myTextbox"  runat="server"/>
var val=<%=myTextbox.ClientID%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's javascript with a snippet of [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)/[ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Page)/[ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) code.

the part in between `<%=` and `%>` is evaluated on the server when the request is made, and the result is inserted into the HTML.

So if, say, the value of `seconds` on the server is 42, then

```
var leave =<%=seconds %>;
```

gets turned into

```
var leave =42;
```

and that's what the browser gets.